# Virtual Host for Ruby Application with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I try to run Redmine with Phusion Passenger. I run virtual host etc, but when i type in web browser my web domain for example: http://mydomain.com/redmine/dispatch.rb, i can download this rb file, this file is not parser by ruby, i don't what is wrong.

I've set and enabled passenger_mod (paths to passenger and ruby are correct) etc.

What I have to check?

Apache configuration is basic:

```
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAdmin "email@email.pl"
  DocumentRoot /home/redmine/public_html

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-error.log
  LogLevel info
```

Ruby and Passenger paths as defualt (i dont change it after isntallation).

Comment: Could you post the config you used for the virtual host?

Comment: I've changed my post (there is virtual host configuration now, but it is very basic)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the DocumentRoot to the `public` folder of the Rails app:

```
DocumentRoot /home/redmine/public_html/public
```

See [the Passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application) for more information.

Comment: Ok, but my "public" is "public_html" and other directories and files i've put under /home/redmine/